# How to copy a file using Java API

Tags: scala, google-cloud-storage

I have the following code :

```
def copyFile(bucket:String, filename:String, newFilename:String) {
    getFile(bucket, filename) match {
      case Some(storageObject) => storage.objects().copy(bucket, filename, bucket, newFilename, storageObject).execute()
      case None => throw new FileNotFoundException("file " + filename + " not found")
    }
  }
```

The code finds the file so I know the bucket, filename and storageobject are valid. For my test, the newFilename is just "test123" so not sure how that could be wrong. Also, why does the method need the storageObject? It seems like having the existing and new buckets and filenames would be enough information. Unfortunately, the error messages are really opaque.

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid argument.",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid argument."
}
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid argument.",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid argument."
}
```

Comment: Can I ask how you're authenticating? You may be running into a known bug. If you have READ_WRITE access, could you try again with FULL_CONTROL access and let me know if that solves the problem?

Comment: Woo woo. Thanks Brandon. I changed the access from read_write to full_control and that worked!

Comment: The bug should now be fixed, by the way. You can once again be able to copy using only the read_write permission.

Comment: Have the same problem. Already used full_control but did not solve the problem.